# Python combining setattr and getattr

Tags: python, class, getattr, setattr

I would like to update the attributes of a class dynamically, but it seems that the combination of setattr and getattr does not work as I would like to use it.

Here is my main class:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
container = Container()
attributes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [True, False], ['red', 'blue', 'green'], [0, 1, -1, -5, 99]]
```

Please note that for the purpose of that example I explicitly constructed the list of attributes and their respective values. However, in the real application of this code, I do not know anything in advance. Neither their numbers, name, or values. This calls for the need to do that dynamically.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
for key, value in zip(attributes, values):
    setattr(container, key, [])
    for val in value:
        setattr(container, key, getattr(container, key).append(val))
```

this part does not work when I run the code. I could save the getattr part in a tmp variable and then call the append method for the list before calling the setattr, but I would like to condense it if possible.

Anyone could explain me why this does not work? What alternative(s) do I have?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "*this part does not work when I run the code*" how? Also, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3):

You are appending to a list in-place. Like all in-place mutation functions, `.append()` returns `None`, so your final line:

```
setattr(container, key, getattr(container, key).append(val))
```

ultimately evaluates to:

```
setattr(container, key, None)
```

Just set a copy of the list on the class:

```
for key, value in zip(attributes, values):
    setattr(container, key, values[:])
```

where the `[:]` creates a copy of `values` by slicing from 0 to `len(values)` in a short-hand notation without needing to loop.

If all you want to do is create an object that provides the keys and values as attributes (much like a `dict` would yet with attribute access instead of item access), you could also use:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, names, values):
        self.__dict__.update(zip(names, values))
```

then run:

```
Container(attributes, values)
```

which removes the need to call `setattr()` in a loop.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Would you know why getattr(container, key, value) seems to work the same as setattr(container, key, value) (once the attribute has been previously set once)?

Comment: @user1713952: it is `getattr(container, key, default)`; if the attribute `key` has not been set on `container`, then `default` is returned instead. Since you already *set*, `key`, `getattr(container, key)` would suffice.

Comment: @JonClements: Why would `defaultdict()` help here? To replace `Container` you mean? The whole append loop is a red herring though, there are no lists being combined, only keys paired up with existing lists.

Comment: @Martijn I'm not 100% awake, but it does look like `Container` could just be that instead...

Comment: Yes, I though of using a dict instead. But I have a couple of specific methods I need to run on those objects and it is more convinient to have them defined within a class. Plus, the syntax of attribute access is more compact with classes isn't it?

Comment: @user1713952: dynamically listing attributes is more cumbersome than listing keys in a dictionary, but having additional methods on the container class is compelling and you can always encapsulate the attribute listing code in a method on the class anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It might help you understand what's going on if you can watch the progress of each step:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__,
            ', '.join(['%s = %s' % (attr, getattr(self, attr))
                for attr in self.__dict__]))
```

Now you can `print container`.  If you do this in the nested loop you'll see that after the first attempt to `setattr` you've clobbered the original list stored in `container.a` (as Martijn noted):

```
for key, value in zip(attributes, values):
    setattr(container, key, [])
    for val in value:
        print 'before:', container
        setattr(container, key, getattr(container, key).append(val))
        print 'after:', container

before: Container(a = [])
after: Container(a = None)
before: Container(a = None)
Traceback (most recent call last): ...
```

The "best" way to do this obviously depends on the real problem—given the shrunken problem Martijn's version is quite appropriate, but perhaps you have to append one item, or extend with multiple items, at some point well after creating some initial `container` instance.